# Switching between drawing GL_POINTS and GL_TRIANGLES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I wrote a simple iphone program that draws a cube with the drawing mode being switched between user taps in the screen view.

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(_program);

glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);
if (_drawGLPointsMode)
    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, sizeof(CubeIndices)/sizeof(CubeIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
else
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(CubeIndices)/sizeof(CubeIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

In the code above _drawGLPointsMode is a BOOL that gets changed between the Taps. The problem i have is that when drawing with GL_TRIANGLES the cube is not drawn. It works when switching to draw with GL_POINTS.

Can anyone please help me out, i feel that i have a fundamental flaw in my code. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

```
glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(CubeVertices), CubeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexIndexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexIndexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(CubeIndices), CubeIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I also try changing GL_STATIC_DRAW to GL_DYANMIC_DRAW, but i get the same result. Also if i run the current code in the iphone simulator everything works correctly it is only when running on the actual device (iphone 4S) that i see this problem. Thanks!

Comment: can you see if the call returns a GL_INVALID_SOMETHING?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. glGetError() returns 0.

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet where you fill the vertex array and the index buffer?

Comment: Are you sure about GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE in your Draw elements? May be it must be GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT?

Comment: @MrPeru, that's not the code snippet I meant, sorry if I was unclear. I meant the actual data you fill vertex and index buffer with. If points work and triangles don't, that can mean that order of indices in the index buffer is wrong or the whole triangle setup is borked.

Comment: @Tutankhamen, still get same result.

Comment: @haffax, maybe i was also unclear on the problem. I only see this when switching between drawing modes at runtime. If i compile/run the program with drawing only GL_TRIANGLES or GL_POINTS it works fine.